# Error in showing laravel data to blade using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have this Contractor Model

```
public function ContractorDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ContractorDetails::class)->select('id', 'contractors_id');
}
```

And ContractorDetails Model

```
  public function Contractors()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contractors::class);
    }
```

I can retrieve all columns under the Contractors Model, but whenever I do this **$contractors->ContractorDetails->id**, it will show this error **"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"** . however when I just use this **$contractors->ContractorDetails**, it is able to show this collection **{"id":6,"contractors_id":24}**

My controller looks like this

```
**$contractors = Contractors::orderby('name')->with('ContractorDetails')->get();**
```

My blade file

```
        <tbody> 
            @foreach($contractors as $contractor)
            <tr class="bg-white lg:hover:bg-gray-100 flex lg:table-row flex-row lg:flex-row flex-wrap lg:flex-no-wrap mb-10 lg:mb-0">
                <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-3 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static">
                    <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-auto left-0 bg-blue-200 px-1 py-1 text-xs font-bold"> Contractor Name</span>
                       {{ $contractor->name }}
                </td>
                <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-3 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b text-center block lg:table-cell relative lg:static">
                    <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-auto left-0  bg-blue-200 px-1 py-1 text-xs font-bold">Status</span>
                    <span class="{{$contractor->status == 0 ? 'px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-yellow-100 text-green-800' : 'px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800' }}"> {{$contractor->status == 0 ? 'onHold' : 'Approved' }}</span>
                </td>

                <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-3 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b text-center block lg:table-cell relative lg:static">
                    <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-auto left-0  bg-blue-200 px-1 py-1 text-xs font-bold">Actions</span>
                    <x-jet-button wire:click="{{ route('ContractorID', [$contractor->ContractorDetails->id])}}" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                        {{ __('EDIT') }}
                        </x-jet-danger-button>
                        <x-jet-danger-button wire:click="confirmContractorDeletion( {{$contractor->id }})" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                            {{ __('Delete') }}
                        </x-jet-danger-button>

                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix.

I create another function under my Contractors Model

```
public function getContractorDetailsAttribute()
{
    return $this->ContractorDetails()->pluck('id')->first();
}
```

Now I can get the ID from the ContractorDetails Model with this

```
$contractors->ContractorDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first as below:

```
isset($contractors->ContractorDetails->id) ? $contractors->ContractorDetails->id : 'No result found'
```

You might have a case where there is not contractorDetails yet.

Comment: Hi Dev. Yes it already has contractordetails. I also tried to dd $contractors. id, and contractors_id are showing. Not really sure where I made  a mistake here.

Comment: I have added my blade file above.